# Can I bundle MIT licensed components in a Apache 2.0 licensed project?

Tags: licensing, software, open-source-software

I am creating a project that I would like to open source and license under the Apache 2.0 License. The project will come with a bundled version of an open source component which is licensed under the MIT license.

Can I bundle MIT licensed components in a Apache 2.0 licensed project?

I would also be interested in an explanation on why the answer is yes or no.

Comment: I want the other way round, I want to add code from apache 2.0 to MIT license. How does one do that?

Comment: I would raise a separate question.

Comment: agreed! I would under normal circumstances but idk what the difference this already closed question (which should not be closed imho) and the one I asked above: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/can-i-copy-code-licensed-under-apache-2-to-a-project-licensed-under-mit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: My attempt here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73848/what-type-of-notices-and-licenses-do-i-need-to-add-when-adding-and-modifying-c

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I realize there's already an answer, but I'd like to go into more detail.

There are generally two kinds of open source software licenses: *[permissive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_free_software_licence)* and *[copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft)* (the latter sometimes called *viral*).

Both are intended to allow people to freely use, modify, and redistribute a work while ensuring the original author gets credit. This contrasts with releasing your work into the public domain, which would allow anyone do literally anything, even claim to be the author.

The difference is that permissive licenses allow you to re-license your derivative works however you like, while copyleft licenses require your derivatives to be licensed under the same license (hence the term viral). The reasons you'd choose either one are philosophical and political and beyond the scope of this answer.

Both the Apache License and the MIT license are permissive, so incorporating MIT licensed code into your Apache licensed project is certainly allowed. Just be sure to attribute the original author for the parts your incorporated and include a copy of the MIT License terms, as required by the license. Go ahead and read it to make sure you get all the details right; it's fairly short and easy for a layperson to comprehend.

Comment: I want the other way round, I want to add code from apache 2.0 to MIT license. How does one do that?

Comment: @Pinocchio - request that the copyright owner of the apache 2.0 licensed works also release what they did under MIT license. OTHERWISE, you will have to maintain the apache 2.0 license. Google for discussion of how to mention TWO permissive licenses (in `notice.md` referring to two license files).

Answer (score 7):

Yep you can.

The MIT license is a very simple, permissive license, that is compatible with just about any open source license you can think of. The only requirements that it holds are a disclaimer of warranty and liability, and attribution.

Since the MIT license is compatible with the Apache 2.0 license (which is also a very permissive license), you can bundle those components together under the Apache license.

Comment: I want the other way round, I want to add code from apache 2.0 to MIT license. How does one do that?

Comment: @Pinocchio - request that the copyright owner of the apache 2.0 licensed works also release what they did under MIT license. OTHERWISE, you will have to maintain the apache 2.0 license. Google for discussion of how to mention TWO permissive licenses (in `notice.md` referring to two license files).